# How to get the role of a user?

Tags: drupal

I have 2 roles in my drupal site. One is admin. The uid is 1. If I visit the profile of another user, say a user with uid 2, is it possible to get that value. I did not want to retrieve it from the url(user/2). Is there any other way to get a user information like uid, role etc while visiting profile of another user. I think $user can be used to get the details of current user only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the details from user id when you are in the profile page of that user use the $account variable. More details in the user-profile.tpl.php template inside ROOT/modules/user.

Example, get user id: `$account->uid;`

Comment: Please, if the above answered your question mark it as Accepted.